# Need to transfer large video from Camera!-app to computer

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPhone 4S and am trying to transfer a 25minute long HD-video that I have recorded through SmugMug's Camera-Awesome (Camera!) app. Once recorded in the app, it stays within that app's interface until you choose to save it via the app onto the camera roll. When trying this option, the app just stalls, even when leaving it for an hour plus. I assume the video is too large to copy.

I am trying the iExplorer app on my MacBookAir. I can find the Documents folder inside the Camera!-folder. But as soon as I access it to view the contents, it simply stalls the app completely. Probably after trying to read the enormous video.

Is there a clever way to transfer this file onto the computer?

I can use iFile on the iPhone to transfer through wifi, but I don't know the Camera! app's Documents folder location on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own solution finally. Through iExplorer on the mac I decided not to try to open that dreaded "Documents" folder inside the Camera!-app folder. Instead i right-clicked it and chose "Export contents" directly. I chose a folder on the harddrive and after a long wait finished copying all the files - including the large video. It turned out it was 3.75Gb in size. iExplorer has no progress bar for this kind of action, so it is impossible to get an idea of what it is doing... Only shows the spinning wheel... Well, solution found! :-)